# Adding my current IP to whitelist on iptables?

Tags: linux, bash, iptables

I'm pretty new to setting up game server but I want to block rcon to every ip except the ones that are whitelisted.

First I'm gonna use this trhough SSH:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 27015 -j LOG --log-prefix "SRCDS-RCON " -m limit --limit 1/m --limit-burst 1
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 27015 -j DROP
```

After that I want that when a user runs a bash script or something similar, it detects the user IP and add it to the whitelist automatically.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you be more specific about this script : will it run on user's machine or on your game server ? Could you tell what GNU/Linux variant  your server runs ?

Comment: On my game server, I use Debian

Comment: How are the users going to connect to the machine ? Via ssh ? As which user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming :

- the bash script is run on the server
- the users logs in using ssh

You could create an ipset :

First, add this rule in iptables :

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m set --match-set whitelist src -p tcp --destination-port 27015 -j ACCEPT
```

Then create a set :

```
sudo ipset -N whilelist iphash
```

Finally, add a script like this, using SSH_CONNECTION environment variable :

```
#!/bin/bash
USER_IP=$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -f1 -d' ')
sudo ipset -A whitelist $USER_IP
```

You could even add those two lines at the end of `/root/.bash_profile` so it gets done automagically when someone connects as `root`.

**However**, this assumes your friends are connecting as root via ssh. Since this is not desirable, you could use a temporary directory to hold the ip addresses, and add a cron job to fill the ipset hash :

- Create `/etc/cron.d/check_ipset` with :

  ```
  * * * * *   root    /usr/local/bin/check_ipset
  ```
- Create `/usr/local/bin/check_ipset` (and `chmod 700`) :

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  for i in `cat /tmp/ipset_pending | sort -u`; do 
    ipset -A whitelist $i
  done
  cat /dev/null > /tmp/ipset_pending
  ```
- Add this to every user's .bash_profile :

  ```
  ...
  echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -f1 -d' ' >> /tmp/ipset_pending
  ...
  ```

Didn't test, so YMMV, but this should be close enough.